# Which remote branch is my git subtree tracking?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-subtree

Let's say there was a remote with a master, as well as a dev branch, and I added it into a subtree:

```
$ git remote add rem [URL]
$ git fetch rem
$ git subtree add -P=./sub rem/dev
```

Now every time I run `git subtree pull -P sub`, the branch rem/dev will be fetched and merged into sub. Ok

But lets say later on **I forgot** whether I added from the master or dev branch. Other than inferring by comparing git logs, is there a way git will tell me which branch of rem is the subtree in sub/ tracking?

Subtrees are tricky...

Comment: I probably answered my own Q. Analyzing the git logs may be easy enough, even if the add was --squash -ed.

Comment: The reason I know git must know this is that git subtree pull doesn't require repo or branch after adding in this way, it knows where to pull from. Even if I add the subtree from different remote branches in different local branches, in each one the command pulls from the appropriate pace.

Comment: Do you know from where `git subtree pull` is getting what branch to pull? If you find that put it as an answer, sounds quite handy.

Comment: Haven't figured it out. Furthermore some times it asks me for a repo/branch also when pulling. It seems inconsistent. Could be somewhere in the .git config files or even in the config set by my client (GitHub for Windows).

Comment: To avoid confusion I now always specify repo (remote) and branch on subtree pull and push

Answer (score 0):

There will be a `.gittrees` file in the root of your working directory, with content such as:

```
[subtree "sub"]
    url = git://example.com/repo.git
    path = sub
    branch = master
```

Comment: I stopped using subtrees by now so can't confirm this. Hopefully someone else can.